# How to make this type of expandable view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am developing an app and got stuck in a layout it is actually an expandable list view with multiple columns can someone please suggest how to achieve this.

I have tried expandable listview but it does not have multiple columns.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBZVg.png

Answer (score 1):

1. The "Session 01", "Session 02", is `RecyclerView`, if it is fetched from a server.
2. The column headers that you see in `CardView` are statically created. i.e. hardcoded in the layout that `RecyclerView` is reusing.
3. Then there's another `RecyclerView` inside the "Session 01", "Session 02" `RecyclerView`, to hold the data regarding the sessions.
4. Then there's the animation to expand/collapse the RecyclerView items, process for which you can see in tutorial here -> [Expandable RecyclerView](https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/)

Comment: They're just created in XML layout of RecyclerView that is being Recycled.